# Array type expected; found: 'java.util.map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>'

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have my variable the first class like:

```
MyClass{
    companion Object{
        @JvmField val foo = mapOf("a" to "b")
    }
}
```

And when I call it from another class like:

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(MyClass.foo["..."]));
```

appears an error saying "Array type expected; found: 'java.util.map 
< java.lang.String,java.lang.String>'"
What is the problem?

**Note that if I do the same call in MyClass it works perfectly**

These are the errors:
[image]

This is my real array values:

```
companion object{
    @JvmField val darkMode = mapOf(
        "bgColor" to "#000000",
        "cardColor" to "#262626"
    )
}
```

The error comes when I call it from a class that extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`
[image]

Comment: It requires a string.

Comment: I didn't specified the map type int the answer, updated now @TaseerAhmad

Comment: You are creating a `Pair` with that, `to` is an infix function that creates a `Pair`.

Comment: So whats the problem? I need an associative array @TaseerAhmad

Comment: Show more of the calling code. Where are you calling this from? What owns the `setBackgroundColor` in your code? Is that a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this:

```
        val foo = mapOf("a" to "Red")
        someView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(foo["a"]))
```

And it works fine, can you share more details about the exception?

### Update

I tried using your `MyClass` exactly as written, except i've replaced the value of `a` by `Red` instead of your `b` string.

Are you using `parseColor` correctly?

```
    /**
     * </p>Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int.
     * If the string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException
     * exception. Supported formats are:</p>
     *
     * <ul>
     *   <li><code>#RRGGBB</code></li>
     *   <li><code>#AARRGGBB</code></li>
     * </ul>
     *
     * <p>The following names are also accepted: <code>red</code>, <code>blue</code>,
     * <code>green</code>, <code>black</code>, <code>white</code>, <code>gray</code>,
     * <code>cyan</code>, <code>magenta</code>, <code>yellow</code>, <code>lightgray</code>,
     * <code>darkgray</code>, <code>grey</code>, <code>lightgrey</code>, <code>darkgrey</code>,
     * <code>aqua</code>, <code>fuchsia</code>, <code>lime</code>, <code>maroon</code>,
     * <code>navy</code>, <code>olive</code>, <code>purple</code>, <code>silver</code>,
     * and <code>teal</code>.</p>
     */
    @ColorInt
    public static int parseColor(@Size(min=1) String colorString) {
        if (colorString.charAt(0) == '#') {
            // Use a long to avoid rollovers on #ffXXXXXX
            long color = Long.parseLong(colorString.substring(1), 16);
            if (colorString.length() == 7) {
                // Set the alpha value
                color |= 0x00000000ff000000;
            } else if (colorString.length() != 9) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color");
            }
            return (int)color;
        } else {
            Integer color = sColorNameMap.get(colorString.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
            if (color != null) {
                return color;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color");
    }
```

### UPDATE 2:

Ok, you said "a class that extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`" but said class is just an abstract class inside the RecyclerView class, so it has no `setBackgroundColor` in it, unless you're doing something like:

`yourViewHolderInstance.itemView.setBackgroundColor`.

So what is the signature of your setBackgroundColor?

Does it look like `public void setBackgroundColor(@ColorInt int color) {` ?

I just added this to my app just for fun:

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder as BaseViewHolder).bind(getItem(position))

// For Filippo :)
holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(MyClass.foo["a"]))
    }
```

And well... it all looks very RED now. :)

#### UPDATE 3

Ok, so according to your last update, you're calling this from Java, therefore you cannot use the Kotlin syntax...

Do this:

```
        final Map<String, String> foo = MyClass.foo;
        yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(foo.get("a")));
```

Obviously, you can avoid the intermediate assignment and go for:

```
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(MyClass.foo.get("a")));
```

I usually prefer the former, especially if you give it all meaningful names and need debugging, but there's no real difference as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: if I do so it works fine, the problem comes when I call foo from another class not in the same  file

Comment: I called it from another class, exactly like yours and it works. What is the value of the `a`? parseColor expects a String with something like "Red" **or** a Hex value like `#FFFFFF`

Comment: The values I put in the question are just examples, this is the real value `"bgColor" to "#000000"`, but i think the problem is not in the values, I mean, why does it expects to receive an Array isn't the map an Array?

Comment: Who is calling `setBackgroundColor`? Is that a `view.setBack...` or ? If you control (or cmd on macOS) click on the method (`setBackgroundColor`) what signatures do you see? When in doubt, instead of packing code like that, separate it in different lines you can debug and see...

Comment: See update 3... you never said you were calling this from Java :)